# How come I can't create this regex with a variable in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a regex to replace all word instances of the string stored in `word` in a target string:

```
regex = re.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b")
```

Python complains with "raise error, v # invalid expression". Why is there an error? I made sure to escape my backslashes, right?

Comment: What is the content of `word`?

Comment: `re.compile("\\b" + "lalala" + "\\b")` works fine for me. What do you get when you `print word`?

Comment: You may want to use `re.escape(word)` if it is user supplied. This will protect your code from crashing if it contains invalid regex pattern stuff. If you do want to allow `word` to contain regex stuff, you probably just need to catch the exception and give appropriate feedback to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `re.compile` doesn't know that part of its input comes from the user, you should use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.escape) to make special characters (like parentheses) in `word` match these characters instead of taking on their special meanings inside regular expressions, like this:
```

```
import re
word = 'Par(ens'
regex = re.compile("\\b" + re.escape(word) + "\\b")
```